# Colocar varias llaves foraneas a un primaria

Tags: mysql

estoy iniciando con SQL y queria saber si es posible colocar varias llaves foraneas de una tabla a una llave primaria de otra tabla, tengo algo mas o menos asi

```
create table producto(
llave int primary key auto_increment,
producto varchar (100));

create table ventas(
clave int primary key auto_increment,
fk_producto1 int,
fk_producto2 int,
fk_producto3 int,
fk_producto4 int,
fk_producto5 int,
foreign key (fk_producto1) references producto (llave),
foreign key (fk_producto2) references producto (llave),
foreign key (fk_producto3) references producto (llave),
foreign key (fk_producto4) references producto (llave),
foreign key (fk_producto5) references producto (llave));
```

El codigo es en MySql y si permite correrlo sin ningun problema, pero no puedo hacer la consulta y me deja datos que estan fuera de la llava primaria de la tabla productos, agradezco

Comment: Viéndolo por encima nada más te puedo decir que no son necesarias todas esas `foreign key`, asumiendo que lo que quieres es relacionar las ventas que se hacen por producto.

Comment: Se porque queres hacer eso, y te digo ya de entrada que no es correcto. La tabla ventas tiene un renglon por venta, y en cada renglon un producto. Si la factura tiene mas de un producto, habra igual un renglon por producto en la factura

Comment: Es decir me quedaria mejor crear un campo con el numero de factura y solo un fk_producto y que se repita el numero de factura por la cantidad de productos??

Comment: Debes añadir el numero de factura en una columna y relacionarla como una `foreign key` y otra tabla que te registre las facturas donde va a estar la llave primaria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según lo que explicaste en los comentarios y lo que se ve en la lógica de tu pregunta, mi recomendación es hacerlo de esta manera:

```
CREATE TABLE facturas (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE producto (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    producto VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE ventas (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_producto INT,
    id_factura INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_producto_ventas FOREIGN KEY (id_producto)
    REFERENCES producto(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_facturas_ventas FOREIGN KEY (id_factura)
    REFERENCES facturas(id)
);
```

No es necesario crear tantas columnas para registrar la cantidad de productos de una factura, basta con tener 2 columnas una que te contenga los productos y otra que te contenga el número de factura. Con eso ya puedes trabajar consultas y relacionarlas como quieras.