# Guardar varias claves foráneas en una fila SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

¿Cómo podría hacer una tabla que me permita por ejemplo, guardar uno o más datos de otra tabla (llave foránea) en una misma fila?

Por ejemplo una tabla llamada *Envíos*: los envíos tienen su *id*, *código*, *dirección*, pero aquí la cuestión... Puede ser enviados por 1 o más compañías (otra tabla llamada *Compañías*)

¿Cómo se tendría que estructurar la tabla para almacenar ese 1 o más?

Estoy trabajando con `MySQL` en `Xampp`.

Comment: Necesitas una tabla de detalles de envíos para que puedas poner cada compañía en una fila. Por otro lado, creo que confundes pedidos con envíos.

Comment: Te falta una tabla intermedia.. deberias leer sobre normalizacion y 3 forma normal.. ahi se explica la tabla que te falta...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!  ah y otra cosa... tu pregunta no tienen nada que ver con Xampp... ni con phpmyadmin...

Comment: ¿En una misma fila almacenar llaves foráneas? No, pero sí en columnas, pues una llave foránea (FK) es una columna o un grupo de columnas en una tabla que identifica de forma exclusiva una fila de otra tabla (o la misma tabla en caso de autorreferencia).

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Colocar varias llaves foraneas a un primaria](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/196394/colocar-varias-llaves-foraneas-a-un-primaria)

Comment: Te puede ayudar [ésta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151051), revisa la parte de *Muchos a Muchos*.